# munmap_chunk error in C

Tags: c, memory

I've been experimenting with dynamic memory allocation and I've come across the munmap_chunk error in C.
Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_input(char **input) {
  *input = (char *) malloc (100);
  *input = "hello world";
}

int main() {
  char *input;
  get_input(&input);
  puts(input);
  free(input);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's what valgrind showed when the program is executed.

```
==4116== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4116== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4116== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4116== Command: ./a.out
==4116== 
hello world
==4116== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4116==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4116==    by 0x400615: main (in /home/mark/Documents/CS32/a.out)
==4116==  Address 0x4006a4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4116== 
==4116== 
==4116== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4116==     in use at exit: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==4116==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==4116== 
==4116== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4116==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4116==    by 0x4005D2: get_input (in /home/mark/Documents/CS32/a.out)
==4116==    by 0x4005FD: main (in /home/mark/Documents/CS32/a.out)
==4116== 
==4116== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4116==    definitely lost: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==4116==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4116==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4116==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4116==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4116== 
==4116== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4116== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why does the free() function behave like this? Also, from the valgrind log, why does my char *input variable not being allocated by malloc()?

Comment: `*input = "hello world";` -> `strcpy(*input, "hello world");`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but what is the main difference between using the strcpy and the normal assignment operator? can't I just use the assignment operator for placing the string "hello world" in the input variable?

Comment: @Mahrrkiee the assignment will overwrite the pointer value in `*input` with a pointer to the global constant `"hello world"`. This one has not been "malloc' ed" and can't be "free'ed". The strccpy will copy the string chars into the "malloc'ed" buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line just after `malloc`. (BTW don't cast malloc return.)

```
*input = "hello world";
```

What happen? `"hello world"` tells the compiler to make some data space in, let's call it data segment, and insert bytes representing the string `"hello world"` including terminating `'\0'` there. Then generate the code which inserts the pointer pointing this string into place where `input` points. It means you made previous line code useless. Just imagine these two assignments one after one `x = 1; x = 2;`. It's what you just done, but `x` is `*input`.
Then the story continues, you return from `get_input()` and end up with this pointer to the string in variable `input` in `main` function scope. Then you feed it into `free()` call. But it is not pointer returned by `malloc()`. You lost it.

If you would like to have "hello world" in input you can either do

```
void get_input(char **input) {
  *input = (char *) malloc (100);
  strcpy(*input, "hello world");
}

int main() {
  char *input;
  get_input(&input);
  puts(input);
  free(input);
  return 0;
}
```

or

```
void get_input(char **input) {
  *input = "hello world";
}

int main() {
  char *input;
  get_input(&input);
  puts(input);
  return 0;
}
```

but now you should be careful what you do with data pointed by `input` because it points to some part of memory you can't modify, `free()` or `realloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign in this way:

```
*input = "hello world"; /* Not modifiable */
```

But then, you don't need to reserve space with `malloc`, `"hello world"` has his own address (at some "read only" segment) and any attempt to modify the string results in undefined behavior, so you are not allowed to `free` it.

If you want a modifiable string:

```
void get_input(char **input) {
    char str[] = "hello world";

    *input = malloc(sizeof(str)); /* Don't cast malloc */
    if (*input == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strncpy(*input, str, sizeof(str));
}
```

or

```
void get_input(char **input) {
    *input = strdup("hello world");
}
```

Note that `strdup` is not standard but it's available on many implementations.

Comment: hi. why can't I assign to an array of char using the assignment operator?
isn't
   char *input = "hello world";
a valid expression in C?

Comment: You can assign using `char *input = "hello world";`, but this string is not modifiable because string literals are placed on read only segments.